# sql: how-to group/partition interleaved table with nulls

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Suppose I have two tables, one describing events with some kind of timestamps and other describing periods (given by their starting time), like this:

```
create table periods (name varchar(16), start int);
insert into periods values
    ('day1', 24), ('day2', 35), ('day3', 49);

create table events (id varchar(16), ts int);
insert into events values
    ('pak', 27), ('mak', 41), ('kew', 30),
    ('sippa', 58), ('fucha', 50), ('den', 28);
```

I want ultimately to match events with periods, but using "interleaving" approach rather than join. Then I imagine "interleaved" set will look like this:

```
select * from (
    (select name as per, s as x, 1 as pri, null as id from periods) 
    union all
    (select null as per, t as x, 2 as pri, id from events)
) v order by x, pri;

+------+------+-----+-------+
| per  | x    | pri | id    |
+------+------+-----+-------+
| day1 |   24 |   1 | NULL  |
| NULL |   27 |   2 | pak   |
| NULL |   28 |   2 | den   |
| NULL |   30 |   2 | kew   |
| day2 |   35 |   1 | NULL  |
| NULL |   41 |   2 | mak   |
| day3 |   49 |   1 | NULL  |
| NULL |   50 |   2 | fucha |
| NULL |   58 |   2 | sippa |
+------+------+-----+-------+
```

And now I want to use `select ... over ... partition by` here so that row with non-null `per` field and following rows with this field nullified will fall into the same partition, over which I can use `min(x)` (or period name somehow).

But I'm puzzled how to write this `partition by`. By what?

Thanks in advance!

*P.S. as about specific SQL dialect, this is about `hive` - that's why trying to avoid join - but I hopefully will be able to adapt hints with syntax for other db engines.*

---

**Solved** - please see the accepted answer below. We need additional nested query in which we apply `COUNT` to the `per` column. This returns amount of rows so far (i.e. above current) which has non-null value for the field. So we got a column which has separate number for every group. Outer query then only need to partition by this column.

Comment: Hive SQL's syntax is very different from the syntax for relational RDBMS.  A query on one won't necessarily port to the other, so I'm tagging your question for Hive.

Comment: Thanks, though "very different" is a bit too strong term in this case, probably, as difference between various relational DBs may be greater... So I hope that if I get the idea itself, I'll probably find a way to find suitable syntax for hive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many databases support the ISO/ANSI standard `IGNORE NULL`s argument to `LAG()`.  This simply allows:

```
select v.*,
       lag(per ignore nulls) over (order by x) as new_per
from ((select name as per, s as x, 1 as pri, null as id from periods 
      ) union all
      (select null as per, t as x, 2 as pri, id from events
      )
     ) v
order by x, pri;
```

Hive doesn't support this option, but you can do the same thing with two levels of window functions:

```
select v.*,
       max(per) over (partition by grp) as new_per
from (select v.*,
             count(per) over (order by x) as grp
      from ((select name as per, s as x, 1 as pri, null as id from periods 
            ) union all
            (select null as per, t as x, 2 as pri, id from events
            )
           ) v
    ) v
order by x, pri;
```

Comment: Thanks. I also have come to this trick with `COUNT` in an additional nested query. I dare to add a short explanation below my question.